# How to query a list of users or a list of groups using SAML AttributeQuery?

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, saml-2.0, openam, opensaml

I can use OpenAM to query list of users or list of groups by using its REST API:

- /openam/json/users?_queryID=*
- /openam/json/groups?_queryID=*

Is there an equivalent of the above using just SAML, such as AttributeQuery?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The goal of the Attribute Query is completing the info that the app has from the IdP that was recieved in Response to the AuthNRequest.

The SP can make an Attribute Query Request to the IdP to complete info of the current logged user, but is not supposed to ask for the user or the group list.

What is the problem making a Rest Request to the Idp? If you use Oauth2 to protect the Tx all is ok.

Comment: The reason I'm looking into a SAML solution is because I could use the same solution for different providers but not restricted to just  OpenAM. Do you know if there's a generic SAML solution to query a list of users or a list of groups? Thanks

Comment: You don't gonna find a "SAML solution" that implements your case due SAML standard does not cover the use case that you are asking for, as I said in my answer. Take a look on the SCIM or the  OpenId Connect standard. You will see that your case is covered and resolved under offering an API protected with Oauth2.

Answer (score 0):

If OpenAM is the IdP it could be configured to send group info in authentication assertion